# HKUnit.massFormatterUnitFromUnit not working with metric prefixes on grams

Tags: objective-c, swift, healthkit

so i've come across this strange issue. I want to extract a `NSMassFormatterUnit` from a `HKUnit` so that i can get a string value out of it. It seems that the method HKUnit.massFormatterUnitFromUnit does not accept kilograms, or any metric-prefixed version of "grams"

```
HKUnit.massFormatterUnitFromUnit(HKUnit(fromString: "kg")) // Fails
HKUnit.massFormatterUnitFromUnit(HKUnit(fromString: "lb")) // No problem
HKUnit.massFormatterUnitFromUnit(HKUnit(fromString: "g")) // No problem
```

Using length formatter poses no issues, for e.g. meters:

```
HKUnit.lengthFormatterUnitFromUnit(HKUnit(fromString: "km")) // All good
```

This is the error i'm presented with:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No mapping for unit kg to NSMassFormatterUnit'
```

Does anyone have a clue to what may be causing this, or is it a bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception thrown by `HKUnit.massFormatterUnitFromUnit` for kilograms is a known bug that is fixed in the iOS 8.2 betas.